# Identify changed rows in datagridview control

Tags: c#, datagridview

How do I loop through a datagridview control (windows forms) and determine which rows have been edited, deleted or are new?

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvr in dgv_OtherEarnings.Rows)
{

}
```

Comment: Same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25060745/return-only-the-changed-rows-of-a-datagridview

Answer (score 0):

No matter what kind of loop but you have to know is ..

**DataGridView.NewRowIndex** will get the index of the row for new record

**DataGridView.IsCurrentRowDirty** will indicating wether the current row has uncomitted changes

Answer (score 0):

This is really old but if it helps anyone...if your datagridview is based on a datatable you can iterate through the changed rows using

`DataTable changes = datatableyourgridisbasedon.GetChanges();`