# Return only the changed rows of a datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a winform that contains a datagridview.  The form is totally disconnected from the data.  The codebehind calls a webservice, which returns a table.  That table becomes the datasource for the datagridview.  Once the datagridview is displayed, a user can edit any row.  Currently, when they hit the 'Update' button, every row in the grid is returned.

Is there a way to return only the changed rows in the datagridview?

UPDATE: Based off Tezzo's answer below, I was able to do this:

```
var changedRows = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified).Rows;
```

Comment: Can you show us the update code? whereto are you returing things (and how)?

Comment: Returned from? The event? It would be much more helpful if some code was provided. You could duplicate the table that is returned from the webservice and then after your user has done their editing, compare each row individually with the one from the origional table, then yeild the rows that dont match. Or keep track of which rows were changed by the CellValueChanged event. There are 2^30 ways of doing this based off the information provided

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [retrieve changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thc1eetk.aspx) in a `DataTable` using `GetChanges`.

So you can use this code with a `DataGridView`:

```
CType(YourDataGridView.DataSource, DataTable).GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified).Rows
```

Comment: For anyone who wants to see the above solution in C#: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69170294/4748475

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with a working solution in C# where I account for a user editing the current cell then performing a Save/Update without moving out of the edited row.  The call to `GetChanges()` won't recognize the current edited row due to its `RowState` still being marked as "`Unchanged`". I also make a call to move to the next row in case the user stayed on the current cell being edited as `GetChange()` won't touch the last edited cell.

```
//Move to previous cell of current edited row in case user did not move from last edited cell
dgvMyDataGridView.CurrentCell = dgvMyDataGridView.Rows[dgvMyDataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[dgvMyDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex - 1];

//Attempts to end the current edit of dgvMyDataGridView for row being edited
BindingContext[dgvMyDataGridView.DataSource, dgvMyDataGridView.DataMember.ToString()].EndCurrentEdit();

//Move to next row in case user did not move from last edited row
dgvMyDataGridView.CurrentCell = dgvMyDataGridView.Rows[dgvMyDataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex + 1].Cells[0];

//Get all row changes from embedded DataTable of DataGridView's DataSource
DataTable changedRows = ((DataTable)((BindingSource)dgvMyDataGridView.DataSource).DataSource).GetChanges();

foreach (DataRow row in changedRows.Rows)
{
        //row["columnName"].ToString();
        //row[0].ToString();
       //row[1].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to get all rows which have been modified in a DataGridView using C#:

```
 DataRowCollection modifiedRows = ((DataTable)YourGridView.DataSource).GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified).Rows;
```